# Missing script: start when deploying nodejs to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm

so I am trying to deploy my nodejs application to heroku.
I have defined the start script in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r mocha-cakes",
    "start": "rm -r -f database/test.db && node app.js",
    "start-win": "del database\\test.db && node app.js"
}
```

I have also added `web: rm -r -f database/test.db && node app.js` to the `Procfile`

However my dyno still crashes with the following log error:

```
2016-06-25T12:27:58.216435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-06-25T12:28:00.503447+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-06-25T12:28:00.502867+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
2016-06-25T12:28:00.504156+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-06-25T12:28:00.503707+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-06-25T12:28:00.506550+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-06-25T12:28:00.506746+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-06-25T12:28:00.506912+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-06-25T12:28:00.516583+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-25T12:28:00.516795+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-06-25T12:28:00.516913+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-06-25T12:28:00.506796+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-06-25T12:28:00.505628+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-25T12:28:01.445657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-06-25T12:28:01.461079+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-06-25T12:28:01.461867+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-06-25T12:28:04.433811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
```

I have checked with the other SO questions and none of the answers have solved my problem. I have tried everything that the other posts have recommended, but haven't found any success yet.

> **Here is the [link](https://github.com/SWEN301-Group-Project/Group-Project/tree/develop) to my repo if you want to see the source code.**

Comment: where is your `procfile` ?

Comment: @John it is in the root of the application. (same location as the package.json file)

Comment: What kind of DB are you using?

Comment: @sznrbrt I am using [sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) database, which is storing the data in database/test.db. (the reason I am deleting the database file is because everytime the nodejs server is started it reads data from an xml file and populates the sqlite database). I have added link to my repo if you are interested in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

In the /database/database.js file after creating the tables if those not exists, there is a db.run query that reads that XML file.

```
db.run('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO managers (username, password) VALUES ("admin","admin")', function(){
    //
    // Dear fellow coder:
    //
    // Once you are done trying to 'optimize' this routine,
    // and have realized what a terrible mistake that was,
    // please increment the following counter as a warning
    // to the next guy:
    //
    // total_hours_wasted_here = 3
    //
    // When I wrote this, only God and I understood what I was doing
    // Now, God only knows
    //
    // Magic, Do not touch

    //initialise the table values from log file
    // I want to read the xml file after the database tables have been created. HACK HACK!!!
    $this.readLogFile();
    console.log('Loaded Data from XML document');
});
```

I'm not sure what's the reason besides testing that you have this in your deployed code. I suppose the reason you want to delete the DB once deployed is that you only need it in testing.

Since Heroku does not seem to like `rm -r -f database/test.db`, I would suggest you to comment this out for deployment or as a more elegant solution add an if statement before calling this DB query that runs it only if you have a TESTING environment variable with a boolean value of true. You should also delete `rm -r -f database/test.db` from your start script.

The other problem with your approach is that the start script runs even before the XML file gets imported, so any manipulation with the db in the start script would not delete it.

Instead, you could also create a query that you call in app.js every time you start your server. That query should empty the whole DB. But why to read it and delete it, when you can just not read it at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Loading data from xml file was a requirement for our group project, so wasn't my choice. Every time a user performs an event, the logFile is updated so that when the system is redeployed it should be able to read data from the logFile and be up-to-date. I know it is not the most elegant solution, but that's all we could do before submission.

Comment: I see now. You might should try to change the `rm -r -f database/test.db` in the start script to `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` then